# alertControllerWithTitle:message:preferredStyle: returns null if called in succession to separate UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uialertcontroller

I have a ViewController for login.  There are two text fields and a login button, nothing overly complex.  There is a validation check on the fields, and if they fail an alertcontroller is shown to tell the user the errors (field is empty, incorrect formatting, etc...). If the validation succeeds the app submits the information to the server and a progress dialog is shown in the form of another alertcontroller.

Here's the problem, if I complete the forms correctly (avoiding the error alertcontroller), the progress alertcontroller is initialized with no problems.  However, if I purposefully fail the validation, showing the error message, then the app crashes when attempting to initialize the next alert controller.

Here are the relevant snippets from MyLoginViewController

```
- (IBAction)loginButtonTouched:(id)sender {
    if ([self validateFields]) {
        [self submitLogin];
    } else {
        [self presentValidationErrors];
    }
}

- (BOOL) validateFields {
    // just some length == 0 and regex checks
    return YES; // if ok
    return NO; // if not ok;
}

- (void) submitLogin {
    [self presentProgressAlertWithTitle:MessageHelperLoginProgressDialog andMessage:MessageHelperWaitProgressDialog];
    // ... some login stuff
}

- (void) presentValidationErrors {
    NSMutableString * validationMessage = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    // ... loops through string collection to create message
    UIAlertController * alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:MessageHelperValidationErrorsDialog message:validationMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:MessageHelperOKActionTitle style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        // we just want to close it
    }];
    [alertController addAction:okAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void) presentProgressAlertWithTitle:(NSString *)title andMessage:(NSString *)message {
    if (_progressAlertController == nil) {
        _progressAlertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:title message:message preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        // prints (null)
        NSLog(@"%s line: %d | progressAlertController: %@", __func__, __LINE__, _progressAlertController);
        UIActivityIndicatorView * spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        // initially broke here because _progressAlertController.view is nil   
        // printed: terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSLayoutConstraint for (null): Constraint must contain a first layout item'
        NSLayoutConstraint * heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_progressAlertController.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:120];
        // ... go on to present progressAlertController
    }
}
```

For clarity,

> presentProgressAlertWithTitle:andMessage:

only fails if it is called anytime after

> presentValidationErrors

has been called.

Comment: Where does _progressAlertController coming from? Where does it get set/defined?

Comment: It's obviously in the .h file... You can see it being set in - presentProgressAlerWithTitle:andMessage